# How to get innerhtml of an element from PHP

Tags: php

I have two files:
mainpage.html and recordinput.php

I need get a div's innerhtml from the mainpage.html in my php file.

I have copied the code here:

in my php file, I have

```
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
//libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dochtml->loadHTMLFile("mainpage.html");

$div = $dochtml->getElementById('div2');
$div2html = get_inner_html($div);
echo "store information as: ".$div2html;


function get_inner_html(DOMNode $elem ) 
{

    $innerHTML = " ";
$children = $elem->childNodes;

foreach ($children as $child)
{
    $innerHTML .= $elem->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $child );
}
echo "function return: ".$innerHTML."<br />";
return $innerHTML;
 }
```

The return is just empty. Any body helps me? I have spent two days on this. I feel like the problem is in here:

```
$dochtml->loadHTMLFile("mainpage.html");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP DOMDocument has already provided the function to retrieve content between your selectors. Here is how you do it

```
$div = $dochtml->getElementById('div2')->nodeValue;
```

So you don't need to make your own function.

Comment: I just found that the code works. It can take the innerhtml from main page. However, it takes the innerhtml when I initiate the page, not the one after change.

Comment: It should only be accepted if it answers the question fully. Does the question include the nodeValue after change? @yunyun

Comment: nodeValue doesn't return HTML. It only works if div2 doesn't have children.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to get the div contents *including all nested tags* then you can do it like this:

```
echo $div->ownerDocument->saveHTML($div);
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/GCbJk

Note that this includes the `div2` tag itself, which you could easily then strip off.